# Any idea why this javascript preventDefault function is not being called in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML that should respond to user interaction. It is a page that I am trying to get to work offline. After I load the page while online I end up with fully rendered HTML. Some of the HTML contains show/hide functionality, and is meant to prevent deafult action of an  element click. For instance, see this:

```
<div id="area49253971_6938" class="component interaction-component float-none clear-none  interaction_booted">
    <div role="status" class="int-prep hidden"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><br> Loading interaction...</div>
    <div>
        <div class="data-field interaction-type">RevealContent</div>
        <div class="interaction_title"></div>
        <div class="interaction_content RevealContent" style="min-height: 400px; width: 400px;">
            <div class="pointer">
                <td>
                    <div id="area49253971_6940" class="component image-component float-left clear-none  booted"><img src="somelink" height="50" width="30" title="" alt="" style="padding-right: 10px;"></div>
                    <p class="body" id="area49253971_6941"><em><strong><a href="#">Some question</a></strong></em></p>
                </td>
            </div>
            <div style="display: block;">
                <td>
                    <p class="body" id="area49253971_6942"><strong>Some answer</strong></p>
                </td>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="interaction_data" style="display: none;">
            <div id="area49253971_6939" class="component table-component float-none clear-none ">
                <div class="component_caption"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The app's code is not working offline (I think due to app's ajax calls and a bunch of other dependencies and app-specific stuff). (By the way, you can see the app code I am trying to rewrite into pure jQuery here: https://jsfiddle.net/0s6xdk9q/1/). So I decided to rewrite the app functionality like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on('click', '.interaction_booted', function () {

        interactionData = $(this).find(".interaction_data");
        this.container = $(this).find(".interaction_content");

        var contentToReveal = ($(this).find('.RevealContent')).children()[1];
        var initialContent = ($(this).find('.RevealContent')).children()[0];

        $(contentToReveal).slideToggle('slow');

        var a = initialContent.find('a');
        a[0].addEventListener("click", function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
        }, false);

    });

});
```

Something is not quite right. Maybe because I have multiple click events. In any case, I confirmed by stepping through the code in Chrome that the variable *a* is indeed the element I expect. All element selectors are working fine. But nothing I do is resulting in this preventDefault from working. I have a feeling there is a simple answer, just not seeing it. Also, I am trying to do this in a way that doesn't require me to add anything to the HTML.

Thoughts?

thanks,
Brian

Comment: Adding another event handler *inside* an event handler is almost  always bad; it's either a simple mistake in code placement or else a design flaw.

Comment: Well after  e.preventDefault(); just return false. it should work

Comment: Try to add live event on that child: `$('.RevealContent a.initial').on('click', function (e) {e.preventDefault()})`

Comment: also why use addEventListener on a[0] when you can do a.on("click",

Comment: Ok, tried out the ideas mentioned here but nothing worked. THen I ended up putting $('.RevealContent a.initial').on('click', function (e) {e.preventDefault()}) outside the $(this).on('click', '.interaction_booted', function () { function, and now it works. I was hoping to have everything contained within that one function, but I guess doing it this way will have to do! thanks, Brian